# Pull data to variable from data layer in Google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

i want to pull data from my datalayer in a Magento store, and store it as a variable in Google tag manager. I use the Welt pixel for creating data layer for the e-commerce data.

How can I put e.g. products.brand in a variable, so I can send it as a parameter in Google analytics 4.

I've tried to put in the following, in a variable - but non of them are right; ecommce.detail.products.brand, e-commerce.brand, products.brand

If I just put e-commerce, the whole array is being inserted as a variable.

Can anyone help me figuring this out?

```
{
  ecommerce: {
    detail: {
      products: [
        {
          name: " Pinot Noir, Gaul",
          id: "5704",
          price: "150.00",
          brand: "Matthias Gaul, Pfalz",
          category: "Shoppen/Vine"
        }
      ]
    },
    currencyCode: "DKK",
    add: {
      products: [
        {
          name: " Pinot Noir, Gaul",
          id: "5704",
          price: "150.00",
          brand: "Matthias Gaul, Pfalz",
          category: "Shoppen/Vine",
          list: "Shoppen/Vine",
          quantity: "6"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the data layer having two `products` items; both having `brand` key/value pairs. You will have to specify through an index value, which one to pull.

Something along the lines of `ecommerce.detail.products.0.brand` if you are interested in the first `products`. Zero indexing is in play with the first item being represented by 0 instead of 1.

Here is [an article by AnalyticsMania](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/pull-data-from-data-layer-google-tag-manager-tutorial/#access-arrays) that explains it in more depth.